# How to get the latest stable version of Firefox?

Tags: automation, api

How to get the latest version of firefox? [This URL](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) was found, but is there no API? I would like to get the latest version, e.g. `58.0.2` so this could be used for other purposes. Just `latest` is insufficient as I require the version in one of my ansible roles to lookup the checksum.

---

At the moment I am considering to parse https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to be parsing HTML in a programmatic way. Avoid it at all costs, if you can. It would be a nightmare to support on-going. There's actually a JSON output that Mozilla provides of all the versions:

https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/firefox_versions.json

**Edit:** Here is a simple bash script example that will always return the latest Firefox version. Make sure you have `jq` & `curl` installed on your system:

```
curl -s https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/firefox_versions.json | jq -r .LATEST_FIREFOX_VERSION
```

This returns:

`58.0.2`

Comment: Huh? I don't understand what you are saying. That is a JSON file that you can programmatically parse `LATEST_FIREFOX_VERSION` to get the latest version. That file is used to _find_ the latest version. You don't need to know the version before you read that file. Just pull out the value for `LATEST_FIREFOX_VERSION` in your script that you write. I've updated my answer to show a code example of this.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Brain fart. Sorry.

Comment: @BoomShadow I totally agree. Perhaps you could answer [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3262/210) as well?

Comment: @BoomShadow and perhaps you could answer [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3443/210) too.

Answer (score 3):

I pulled this from the [Firefox Chef cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/firefox) (in particular [this](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/firefox/blob/master/libraries/default.rb) .rb file). This an example of the request they use to get the latest version based on OS and language.

```
https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest#&os=win#&lang=#en-US
```

It adheres to the following format:

```
https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-{VERSION_NUMBER}#&os={OS_ABBREVIATION}#&lang=#{LANGUAGE_ABBREVIATION}
```

I searched around for official api documentation, but couldn't find anything. If I do, I will post a link to it in this answer.